# Issue exporting module NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this directory structure:

- app/router.js
- app/oauth2-home-client/oauth2-client.js

And the sources:

**app/oauth2-home-client/oauth2-client.js**

```
    //SOME CODE

    exports.Bearer = {

            authenticate : passport.authenticate('bearer', { session : false }),

            initialize : passport.initialize()

            // session : passport.session()
    };
```

**app/router.js**

```
var oauth2 = require('./oauth2-home-client/oauth2-client');

console.log(JSON.stringify(oauth2.Bearer));

//SOME CODE
```

When I print `oauth2.Bearer` (and `oauth2`, too) content, I get `{}`. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your `router.js` located?

Comment: In `app/`, same directory that `oauth2-home-client` folder. I have edited my question for clarity.

Comment: Try this `var oauth2 = require('oauth2-home-client/oauth2-client');` instead  of `var oauth2 = require('./oauth2-home-client/oauth2-client');`

Comment: Also try putting quotes around authenticate and initialize in JSON.

Comment: You should show what you want to do with `oauth2.Bearer`  currently it is just possible to tell why you get this result, but not how to solve it. Do you want to do `oauth2.Bearer.authenticate()` which then should call `passport.authenticate('bearer', { session : false })`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
exports.Bearer = {
  authenticate : passport.authenticate('bearer', { session : false }),
  initialize : passport.initialize()
  // session : passport.session()
};
```

Will result in:

```
exports.Bearer = {
  authenticate :undefined,
  initialize : undefined
};
```

because both `passport.authenticate`  and  `passport.initialize`  return `undefined`.

And the *keys*  having the value `undefined` are omitted by [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

> [...]If undefined, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array).[...]

Answer (score -1):

Its value may point to the module instantiation.
Have you try this?

```
module.exports = {...};
```